# Tool tip Does not working properly when i add the php variable

Tags: php, html, css

I return some HTML span tag with PHP variables, the span tag contain title field, i binding my PHP data into the title field but it only accept the first sentence of my PHP value so, it does not work properly, here I attach my code.

```
 $row['task_name'] = 'kmg kumar';
        return "<span class='maxname' title = ".$row['task_name'].">".$row['task_name']."</span>";
```

Hereafter return value i will show in html page when i mouse hover the label it only show "kmg", it does not show remaining  "kumar" portion

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
// Note There you miss title='something goes here' like syntax for the element.

```
  $row['task_name'] = 'kmg kumar';
     return "<span class='maxname' title = '".$row['task_name']."'>".$row['task_name']."</span>";
```

Comment: If this article is related to your problem and solves your issue then use it as an answer to help another user to find the best option for there solution.